# CSS alignment of a text

Tags: html, css, alignment

Quick points, having trouble aligning a text in a table as it wraps the second line. I have treid justifying and block and in-line etc Appreciate any suggestions. What I need is that the second line aligns exactly under the first line eg: starts at vfdbd....[image]

[image]

Comment: Plz don't use Image here, instead try ctrl+m and add your code.

Comment: Your code is using `::before` sudo element on text node. @user6849557 ' s answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

put the text inside a span element with `display: inline-block;`. That way the text start on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper needs to have text justification applied via CSS:

```
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
```

In general, browsers do a crappy job as fully-justified text compared to "typesetting" applications for print. In general, full-justification on browsers makes text HARDER to read and should generally be avoided.

Comment: Can U Add Your Code Or Screen Shot .How It Looks Like

Comment: I had never heard of `text-justify`: seems it's an old IE-only property that made its way into [CSS Text Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#text-justify) (only supported by that browser?). If it's some sort of advanced word-spacing, seems unrelated to OP problem though

Answer (score 1):

No need for an extra element if you know the width of the symbol (text or image) you're adding to the left of your first line.

The trick is to add a negative text-indent counter-balanced by a positive margin-left. Say you add a 40px-wide internet kitten via :pseudo + 8px of padding between image and text: the element then needs following first CSS rule:

```css
/* Image is 40px-wide and we want it at 8px from text */
.txt-indent {
  margin-left: 48px;
  text-indent: -48px;
}
.txt-indent:before {
  content: url(https://placekitten.com/40/40);
  padding-right: 8px;
}
body {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<p class="txt-indent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, natus soluta! Itaque, corporis veritatis quisquam ut debitis sed incidunt enim sit ratione sint repellat aliquid sunt rerum commodi asperiores ipsa!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for text-indent, was unknown to me until now.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up increasing line-height to make it work.